# How to locate the tablespace objects that have grown suddenly?

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

In my Oracle 11g database, I have one of my tablespace that has grown suddenly during the night.
I would like to find the tablespace objects (e.g. tables or index) that have grown suddenly as occupied space.
Is there a script that can do this for me?

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't 'is there a script'.  The question is 'is that information in the database?'  ***IF*** you are licensed for the Diagnostic Pack, you can query the various DBA_HIST* views, as documented in the Database Reference.  If you are not licensed for that, then you would have had to created your own processes for tracking segment sizes.

Comment: Dear @EdStevens, thank you for the answer, i am licensed for the Diagnostic Pack. **Can you please advise me which of these views i should check**, so in which view i can find these information?

Comment: Well, I am NOT licensed for the Diagnostic Pack, so am not all that familiar with it.